# workling client stops in a few seconds after start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rabbitmq, amqp, workling

Hi I'm trying to use RabbitMQ instead of Starling I've configured my
app and everything seems to be fine but when i run 'script/
workling_client start' it starts to work and ends in a few seconds and
I can't get why

My app works perfectly with Starling

I'm using Fedora 13 ruby 1.8.7 rails 2.3.8 mongrel(configured
according to http://github.com/tmm1/amqp)

The log file is empty but the code iside `listen` action definitely executes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in mongrel because I used not evented version and AMQP. So to get AMQP work I must start EM in my development.rb Workling also starts it's own machine after loading rails env. So it started EM while loading rails and later tried to start another one. 
[Qusion](http://github.com/danielsdeleo/qusion) solved all problems and now everything works fine :)